# get File.class name android?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

My problem is that I use the same cardAdapter.class for two recyclerview classes (users.class and list.class).

But I want to do something different in each, for this I need to know what class user is from my cardadapter - users.class or list.class.

I tried:

```
class CardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CardAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    public String class_name = this.getClass().getSimpleName();
```

but it returns: `CardAdapter`

any ideas how can I get the class that is using cardAdapter? (users.class or list.class) instead of the cardAdapter itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send your context(Fragment, Activity etc.) to adapter via constructor.

```
CardAdapter adapter = new CardAdapter(yourDataList, mContext)
```

And use if case like below:

```
if(mContext instanceof ActivityUsers){
    //Do what you need
}else if(mContext instanceof ActivityList){
    //Do what you need
}
```

There are many ways to do it, it is one of the easiest one.